# Properly escaping SSH command in PHP

Tags: php, shell, ssh, escaping, libssh2

I have an SSH command that I'd like to execute with libssh2 in PHP:

```
sh -c '
  rm -f /tmp/command.log
  sleep 3 &
  screen -p 0 -X stuff "\
script -a -c \"ls -l\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
"
  wait
  cat /tmp/command.log
'
```

I can't seem to escape it properly though, so SSH receives it exactly as above. I need to wrap it in double quotes so I can get PHP variables in there as well (ls -l will become $command).

I have tried:

```
"sh -c '
  rm -f /tmp/command.log
  sleep 3 &
  screen -p 0 -X stuff \"\
script -a -c \\"ls -l\\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
\"
  wait
  cat /tmp/command.log
'"
```

as well as:

```
"sh -c '
  rm -f /tmp/command.log
  sleep 3 &
  screen -p 0 -X stuff \"\
script -a -c \\\"ls -l\\\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
\"
  wait
  cat /tmp/command.log
'"
```

The first of which returns a PHP error and the second of which doesn't run the command.

The whole function (after the edit Morgan Wilde suggested):

```
    function runShellCommand($command, $host, $user, $pass, $port){
        if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("Fail: function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
        if(!($con = ssh2_connect($host, $port))){
            return "Unable to establish connection. Is your server offline?";
        } else {
            if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, $user, $pass)) {
                return "Failed to authenticate. Please ensure your server's password matches our records.";
            } else {
                $run = <<<HEREDOC
sh -c '
rm -f /tmp/command.log
sleep 3 &
screen -p 0 -X stuff "\
script -a -c \"touch /root/test234\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
"
wait
cat /tmp/command.log
'
HEREDOC;
                if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con,  $run ))) {
                    return "Could not run command.";
                } else {
                    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                    $data = "";
                    while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                        $data .= $buf;
                    }
                    fclose($stream);
                    if(empty($data)){
                        return "sh-4.1# $command\n\n";
                    } else {
                        return "sh-4.1# $command\n$data\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `HEREDOC` string quoting? I haven't tried it, but it works for other use cases.

```
$command = <<<HEREDOC
sh -c '
rm -f /tmp/command.log
sleep 3 &
screen -p 0 -X stuff "\
script -a -c \"ls -l\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
"
wait
cat /tmp/command.log
'
HEREDOC;
```

More on that here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Strange, it's still not running the command properly. I'll post the whole function.

Comment: @JamesHadley Well first of all make sure the sequence of statements you provide the `ssh2_exec` method is valid and makes sense. I cannot clarify that since I have no expertise in that, my answer was solely based on the need to **properly escape a ssh command**. I think if you don't fully understand if the command is well formed you might need to create a new question. Am I right?

Comment: The command is well formed - it runs on the terminal just fine. Admittedly the title was a little narrow as I thought the problem was simply related to the escaping, though it seems there's a further problem here. I wonder whether libssh2 doesn't support multi-line commands altogether?

Comment: @JamesHadley definitely check out this comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php#59324

Comment: Tried that function as well and I think the conclusion is libssh2 doesn't like multi-line commands. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("rm -f /tmp/command.log\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("sleep 3 &\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("screen -p 0 -X stuff \"\
script -a -c \\\"ls -l\\\" /tmp/command.log; kill -USR1 $!
\"");
...
?>
```